# transforming url's, python

Tags: python, regex, url

I have a txt file which contains some url's:

```
[http://igu.org.ru/ International Geographical Union - Russian National Committee]
[http://www.geografos.org Colegio de Geógrafos - España]
[http://www.geografs.org Col.legi de Geògrafs - Catalunya]
[http://www.geografs.org]
```

now I want to transform this external links in the following way (in the fixed order):

replace "`[url any text]`" with "`any text`", where "`url`" is an URL (e.g., starts with "http://").

replace "`[url]`" with "`url`"

```
import re
def openfile(filename):
    with codecs.open(filename, encoding="utf-8") as F:
        replace = F.read()
        replace = re.sub(r'\[http://.+ ...) # should replace "[url any text]" with "any text"
        replace = re.sub(...) # should replace "[url]" with "url"
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
re1 = re.compile(r'\[(http[^\s]*)\s(.*)\]')
re2 = re.compile(r'\[(http[^\s]*)\]')
with codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as F:
    text = F.read()
    pre_filter = re1.sub('\g<2>', text)
    result = re2.sub('\g<1>', pre_filter)
```

to process the your text. 
For further informations in the background you can read: 
http://docs.python.org/howto/regex.html#search-and-replace

Comment: how do you explain \g<2> and \g<1>?
And how do I use it in the module-level re.sub() function?

Comment: In the first regex you see, that the first group is in the hook '()', this is the '(http[^\s]*)' and the second group is the text '(.*)', so what the re.sub statement does is to replace the whole text or each matched element with the second group.

Comment: use pre_filter = re.sub(r'\[(http[^\s]*)\s(.*)\]', '\g<2>', text) and 
result = re.sub(r'\[(http[^\s]*)\]', '\g<1>', pre_filter) instead of re1 and re2 if you want to :)